# How do I reference a custom field of datatype hierarchy in a Workflow rule

Tags: workflow, hierarchy

I have a custom field on my Account object which is of type Hierarchy (which is for the Object User). I have never come across this before, and I cannot find out how to reference that field in my Workflow rule criteria.
I have included it like this:

`Owner:User.headofDepartment__c` , but I get the following error:
Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'and()'. Expected Boolean, received Lookup(User)

Tia.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add an operator.  e.g. if you want the workflow rule to fire when the Owner does not have a Head of Department then use the formula below in your function.  Bear in mind that this might fire if the owner is a Group as the formula will evaluate to TRUE.

```
Owner:User.headofDepartment__c = ""
```